# Next.js SSG Image Optimization at Build Time

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, next.js

### Problem

I am trying to use **image optimization for local files inside the `public` directory** in a **`SSG` Next.js project**.

There have been quite a few discussions on Github about introducing the possibility to use the `next/image` for image optimization at build time. However, at this moment, the `next/image` component does not work with the static site export.

See: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/19065

---

### Solutions Attempts / Ideas

From what I could find, there are a few different actions that can be taken:

##### 1. Set the `unoptimized` flag in the `next.config.js` file to completely disable image optimization for all `next/image` components

While this gets rid of the errors, pictures are now unoptimized in the build output directory.

##### 2. Replace all `<Image />` tags with standard `<img />`

Like the first approach, this leads to images being unoptimized. If you are using `ESLint`, you would also have to disable the `no-img-element` rule to get rid of the errors.

##### 3. Use a third-party library specifically for Next.js to enable image optimization at build-time

I was only able to find two libraries that can be used to achieve this. The recommended package in the GitHub thread is called [`next-optimized-images`](https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-optimized-images) and seems to be the more popular solution to this problem. However, by looking at the repositories commit history, it becomes obvious that this project has been abandoned and is no longer updated for newer versions of Next.js. The `README.md` of this project mentions an upcoming third version (found on the canary branch) which hasn't seen a new commit in 3 years as well.

The other project I was able to find is called [`next-image-export-optimizer`](https://github.com/Niels-IO/next-image-export-optimizer). This package is updated quite frequently but it also requires a lot of steps to be set up and necessitates changes throughout the whole application.
I dislike the idea of replacing the Image component with some library-specific image component.

##### 4. Implement a custom custom image loader

This is one of the recommended methods mentioned in the GitHub issue. I was, however, only able to find [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-image-loader-config) on how to do this using third-party image optimization services (such as Cloudflare). It is unclear to me if this technique can be used to do local image optimization at build time.

##### 5. Manually optimize new images before building the project

It may be possible to modify the `build` script in the `package.json` file to execute another script that optimizes all recently added images stored outside the `public` folder and copy those optimized versions into the `public` folder. Modifying the `build` script inside the `package.json` file might break automatic deployment with hosting sites such as Vercel.

---

Obviously, I could just deploy my application using SSR instead of using the `export` command. But I would like to avoid running a server just for the image optimization feature of Next.js.

Since this issue was last updated on Github a while ago, I was wondering **if there are simpler approaches to optimize the images in the `/public/` directory of a SSG project** when using the `export` command to build the files.

Comment: Did you figure something out? Thanks :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I eventually migrated my project to Astro which has working image optimization out of the box, and I am quite happy with it. They also improved image handling and optimization a lot with recent releases.